# Xamarin WCF BasicHttpBinding - Method or operation is not implemented

Tags: c#, methods, xamarin, basichttpbinding, notimplementedexception

Quick background info: 
There is a wcf with authentication which use BasicHttpBinding. The Dataservice.cs contains the dataserviceclient based on the service metadata (generated using svcutil).

I first made an console app using the code and it worked perfectly then I made an xamarin android project. I copied the code. referenced system.runtime.serialization and system.servicemodel. This gives me an The method or operation is not implemented error.

Main code:

```
     base.OnCreate(bundle);


        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://serviceurl/service1.svc");
        PermissiveCertificatePolicy.Enact("CN=MySelfSignedCert");

        var client = new DataServiceClient(binding, address);

        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Passord";

        try
        {

            var projects = client.GetDataTest(1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex.Message;

        }
```

I am new to Xamarin programming so I could be missing key point here, but please remember that this works as an console app and the service is online (not localhost).

```
Unhandled Exception:
```

System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

07-20 11:35:39.704 D/Mono    ( 1452): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
07-20 11:35:39.704 D/Mono    ( 1452): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
07-20 11:35:39.704 D/Mono    ( 1452): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
07-20 11:35:39.704 D/Mono    ( 1452): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
07-20 11:35:39.704 D/Mono    ( 1452): Probing '__android_log_print'.
07-20 11:35:39.704 D/Mono    ( 1452): Found as '__android_log_print'.
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452): System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding.CreateSecurityBindingElement () [0x00025] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/BasicHttpBinding_4_5.cs:125 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding.CreateBindingElements () [0x00006] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/BasicHttpBinding_4_5.cs:98 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding..ctor (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding) [0x00000] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/CustomBinding.cs:60 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.CreateContext (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection parameters) [0x00000] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/Binding.cs:96 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.CanBuildChannelFactory[TChannel] (System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection parameters) [0x00011] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/Binding.cs:267 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory () [0x000ad] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory.cs:199 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening () [0x00006] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory.cs:383 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ProcessOpening () [0x00017] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/CommunicationObject.cs:276 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open (TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/CommunicationObject.cs:169 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open () [0x00000] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/CommunicationObject.cs:164 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.EnsureOpened () [0x00058] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory.cs:297 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[TChannel].CreateChannel () [0x00000] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory_1.cs:108 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[TChannel].CreateChannel () [0x00000] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:266 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[TChannel].get_InnerChannel () [0x0000b] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:186 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[TChannel].get_Channel () [0x00000] in

/Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:192 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at DataServiceClient.GetProjects (Int32 firmaid) [0x00001] in C:\Users\username\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\somethingMobileApp

\somethingMobileAppAndroid\DataService.cs:10752 
07-20 11:35:39.708 I/MonoDroid( 1452):   at somethingMobileAppAndroid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0006d] in C:\Users\username\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects

\somethingMobileApp\somethingMobileAppAndroid\MainActivity.cs:50 
07-20 11:35:39.708 D/Mono    ( 1452): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
07-20 11:35:39.712 D/Mono    ( 1452): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
07-20 11:35:39.712 D/Mono    ( 1452): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
07-20 11:35:39.712 D/Mono    ( 1452): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
07-20 11:35:39.716 D/Mono    ( 1452): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
07-20 11:35:39.716 D/Mono    ( 1452): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
07-20 11:35:39.716 D/Mono    ( 1452): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
07-20 11:35:39.716 D/Mono    ( 1452): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
An unhandled exception occured.

07-20 11:35:42.112 E/mono    ( 1452): 
07-20 11:35:42.112 E/mono    ( 1452): Unhandled Exception:
07-20 11:35:42.112 E/mono    ( 1452): System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
07-20 11:35:42.112 E/mono    ( 1452):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:c637c172-2e79-4a17-a720-5e2325d945f7 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
07-20 11:35:42.112 E/mono    ( 1452):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Object:c637c172-2e79-4a17-a720-5e2325d945f7 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
In mgmain JNI_OnLoad
07-20 11:35:42.112 E/mono-rt ( 1452): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
07-20 11:35:42.112 E/mono-rt ( 1452):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:c637c172-2e79-4a17-a720-5e2325d945f7 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
07-20 11:35:42.112 E/mono-rt ( 1452):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Object:c637c172-2e79-4a17-a720-5e2325d945f7 (intptr,intptr,intptr)

Any suggestion ? :)

Comment: The service url and username/Passord is ok in real code but masked with generic string here.

Comment: I'd recommend adding at least the first couple of lines of the stack trace from the "The method or operation is not implemented error" exception.  At the moment the question does not mention which particular method or operation is actually missing.

Comment: Very good point. I will add it to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is likely caused by the current limitations of the WCF implementation in Mono and Xamarin.Android.  To make a guess, the authentication mode could be the core of the problem:

> Authentication with `BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport` is supported:
>   http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#Calling_a_WCF_Service_with_Client_Credential_Security
>
> Authentication with `BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential` is not (yet) supported:
>   http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6493/wcf-basichttpbinding-with-transportwithmessagecredential-username-failure-ios-and-android

(From http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/44741/#Comment_44741)

Comment: I guess, but the exception is on the client.GetDataTest.

Comment: I guess this is the correct answer its seems like xamarin system.servicemodel is 2.0.5.0 and console app windows system.servicemodel is 4.0.0.0 . Even though the documentation says its supported :(

Answer (score 0):

From the xamarin documentation:

Using Client Credential Security
WCF services may also require the service clients to authenticate using credentials. The Xamarin platform does not support the WS-Security Protocol, which allows clients to send credentials inside the SOAP message envelope. However, the Xamarin platform does support the ability to send HTTP Basic Authentication credentials to the server by specifying the appropriate ClientCredentialType:

basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
Then, basic authentication credentials can be specified:

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = @"foo";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = @"mrsnuggles";

Found at: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#wcf

Indicates that the client authentication is implemented

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer which is why i marked the earlier answer as correct.

Xamarin doesn't support TransportWithMessageCredential.
They do support TransportCredentialOnly.

BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential) Gives the error when calling the service.

The problem I have is that MSDN points out that TransportCredentialOnly should be used with caution as its send the  username and password in plain text over http.

I hope xamarin would implement a more secure way of talking with wcf. Such as TransportWithMessageCredential or WSHTTPBINDING.